# (D3) dispatching "mousedown" event to selection with drag behaviour throws error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Title says pretty much all, trying to dispatch mousedown event to selection that have drag behaviour set up throws "TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined", example is in snippet.

I'm trying to think of some workaround, because I have to pass mousedown to element I add at mouse cursor to drag it without pressing mouse button twice. Any input is very appreciated.

```js
d3.select('#dragable').call(d3.drag().on('drag', function() {
  d3.select(this).style('left', d3.event.x + 'px');
  d3.select(this).style('top', d3.event.y + 'px');
}))

d3.select('#dragable').dispatch('mousedown');
```

```css
#dragable {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="dragable">

</div>
```

EDIT:

I tinkered around in debugger, and it seems that when firing from dispatcher, CustomEvent object passed to d3-drag is missing view variable. So theoreticaly adding Window object to it could fix it. I have no idea though how to do it, or rather how to do it without modifying d3 source.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out I was using wrong tool for the job, because selection.dispatch() is used for dispatching custom events. To dispatch mouse event I had to use `.dispatchEvent(event)` method with MouseEvent.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

`.on('start', function() {
  dispatch.call("mousedown", this);
});`

to `drag` function and after

```
var dispatch = d3.dispatch('mousedown');
dispatch.on('mousedown', function(){ });
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error. According to debugger error is thrown @ line 5 of nodrag.js (https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/master/src/nodrag.js) and if fired by mouse it gets Window object in view variable, but this object is missing when fired from dispatch.